# try catch does not work in gridview in ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to define try catch for a gridview in asp.net on C#, I have used several method such as show on the label or java script but they didn't work,
thanks to help me 
here is my code

```
protected void AddNewSP(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            { 
                string Id = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtId")).Text;
                string PartName = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPartName")).Text;
                string Coverage = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCoverage")).Text;
                string SupplierName = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtSupplierName")).Text;
                string Status = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtStatus")).Text;                           
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "insert into SupplySituation(Id, PartName, Coverage, SupplierName, Status) " +
                    "values(@Id, @PartName, @Coverage, @SupplierName, @Status);" +
                    "select Id, PartName, Coverage, SupplierName, Status from SupplySituation ORDER BY Id DESC";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Id;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PartName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = PartName;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Coverage", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Coverage;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SupplierName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = SupplierName;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Status;
                    GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('" + ex.Message.ToString() + "');", true);
                }         
        }

private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
            return dt;           
        }
```

in fact there is no any error or any action , when I click on the "ADD" button with wrong data nothing happens, I except to show the error but nothing happens

my front code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="750px"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Names="Arial"
                                Font-Size="11pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#C2D69B"
                                HeaderStyle-BackColor="green" AllowPaging="True" ShowFooter="True"
                                OnPageIndexChanging="OnPagingSP" OnRowEditing="EditSP"
                                OnRowUpdating="UpdateSP" OnRowCancelingEdit="CancelEditSP">

                                <Columns>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id">
                                        <ItemTemplate>

                                            <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server"
                                                Text='<%# Eval("Id")%>'></asp:Label>

                                        </ItemTemplate>

                                        <FooterTemplate>

                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtId" Width="20px"
                                                MaxLength="5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="50px" HeaderText="PartName">

                                        <ItemTemplate>

                                            <asp:Label ID="lblPartName" runat="server"
                                                Text='<%# Eval("PartName")%>'></asp:Label>

                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <EditItemTemplate>

                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPartName" runat="server"
                                                Text='<%# Eval("PartName")%>'></asp:TextBox>

                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterTemplate>

                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPartName" Width="100px"
                                                MaxLength="20" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                                        </FooterTemplate>

                                        <ItemStyle Width="30px" />

                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="100px" HeaderText="Coverage">

                                        <ItemTemplate>

                                            <asp:Label ID="lblCoverage" runat="server"
                                                Text='<%# Eval("Coverage")%>'></asp:Label>

                                        </ItemTemplate>

                                        <EditItemTemplate>

                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCoverage" runat="server"
                                                Text='<%# Eval("Coverage")%>'></asp:TextBox>

                                        </EditItemTemplate>

                                        <FooterTemplate>

                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCoverage" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                                        </FooterTemplate>

                                        <ItemStyle Width="100px" />

                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="SupplierName">

                                        <ItemTemplate>

                                            <asp:Label ID="lblSupplierName" runat="server"
                                                Text='<%# Eval("SupplierName")%>'></asp:Label>

                                        </ItemTemplate>

                                        <EditItemTemplate>

                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSupplierName" runat="server"
                                                Text='<%# Eval("SupplierName")%>'></asp:TextBox>

                                        </EditItemTemplate>

                                        <FooterTemplate>

                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSupplierName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                                        </FooterTemplate>

                                        <ItemStyle Width="150px" />

                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="Status">

                                        <ItemTemplate>

                                            <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server"
                                                Text='<%# Eval("Status")%>'></asp:Label>

                                        </ItemTemplate>

                                        <EditItemTemplate>

                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtStatus" runat="server"
                                                Text='<%# Eval("Status")%>'></asp:TextBox>

                                        </EditItemTemplate>

                                        <FooterTemplate>

                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtStatus" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                                        </FooterTemplate>

                                        <ItemStyle Width="150px" />

                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField>

                                        <ItemTemplate>

                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemove" runat="server"
                                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id")%>'
                                                OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to delete?')"
                                                Text="Delete" OnClick="DeleteSP"></asp:LinkButton>

                                        </ItemTemplate>

                                        <FooterTemplate>

                                            <asp:Button ID="btnAddNewSP" runat="server" Text="Add"
                                                OnClick="AddNewSP" />

                                        </FooterTemplate>

                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />

                                </Columns>

                                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#C2D69B" />

                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="Green" />

                            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: What is your exact problem?

Comment: Maybe there aren't any errors to catch?

Comment: `I have used several method such as show on the label or java script` Where are the codes?  `but they didn't work,` What errors do you get?

Comment: Where's your `GetData()` function

Comment: Don't see anywhere you mentioned what doesn't work?

Comment: Are you saying you need a way to capture the error?  Here are a bunch of ideas, including use of ELMAH, a nuGet packkage for logging errors in the db. http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/aspnet-error-handling

Comment: guys , I edited my post to show detail, in fact there is no error when I click on the add button with wrong data, nothing happens , I want to see error message on the label or javascript message

Comment: start by inserting break points (in your code behind)
I would put one before try, just to see you are getting there. then you can hit F10 key to run line by line to see where and if your code breaks

Comment: @DaniDev : I tried to debug and I saw the error message on the catch in VS but there nothing in my browser , I want to show error in the browse :(

Comment: In that case there is maybe something wrong in your:
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock
and/or in your front end code.
Please post your front end code

I think Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),    is wrong. 
Try "alert" instead

Comment: @DaniDev: I posted my front code , could you please take a look

Comment: It seems like you should be focused on solving your error rather than displaying it. If you were already seeing the error using a break point then try and address it rather than focusing on the seemingly trivial task of displaying it (?)

Answer (score 0):

Try to substitute your catch block

```
catch (Exception ex)
            {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('" + ex.Message.ToString() + "');", true);
            }
```

with the following:

```
 catch (Exception ex)
     {
          ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + ex.Message.ToString() + "');", true); 
     }
```

Comment: I see this error : the name thisGetType() does not exist in the current context

Comment: My bad, there was a typo in my code. I corrected to: this.GetType(), 
If you are getting the error it means you are on the right track.
Please try again

Comment: questions:
1. Are you certain that the catch block is even getting reached?
2. Try running an alert("test") on your page just to make sure you don't have script disabled.